# Do we ever study "mixed" categories?

Tags: category-theory

Consider a category whose object class includes the class of all topological spaces *and* the class of all topological groups. Furthermore, let the hom-sets between any two objects be the usual hom-sets in the category of topological spaces, unless both objects are topological groups, in which case the hom-set between them will be the usual hom-set in the category of topological groups.

Are "mixed" categories such as this ever studied?

Comment: I don't know the general answer, but this category seems not closed under composition: consider the composition of $f: G \to T$ and $g: T \to H$ where $T$ is a topological space and $G, H$ are topological groups. It won't be a group homomorphism in general.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Qiaochu, i wouldn't! Just trying to get a gauge on the extent to which its useful to view mathematical structures as belonging to unique categories.

Comment: I think it's a little limiting to view view mathematical structures as belonging to *unique* categories. Fortunately we have functors! Any topological group is also a topological space because there is a forgetful functor from the former category to the latter, and so forth. Functors connect categories in the same way that morphisms connect objects. (You can use this setup to study, for example, continuous maps from a space to a topological group, which are given by morphisms of the form $d \to F(c)$ where $F : C \to D$ is the forgetful functor from topological groups to topological spaces.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

if categories $\Bbb A$ and $\Bbb B$ are disjointly contained in a (bigger) category $\Bbb H$ as full subcategories, and suppose that $\Bbb H$ has no other objects, then I call $\Bbb H$ a *bridge* between $\Bbb A$ and $\Bbb B$, see [my paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~aladar/MrtCtx.pdf).

As Matt E. answered, your particular example is *not* a bridge, because we allow both directions $\Bbb A\not\to\Bbb B$ and $\Bbb B\not\to\Bbb A$. However, if we keep only one direction, say $\Bbb A\not\to\Bbb B\ $ (letting the homsets $\hom(b,a):=\emptyset$), we *do* get a category.

Such *directed* bridges from $\Bbb A$ to $\Bbb B$ straightly correspond to *profunctors*, i.e. functors of the form $\Bbb A^{op}\times\Bbb B\to\Bbb{Set}\ $ (just take the restriction of the hom functor). In the paper I show that bridges are just the so called *Morita contexts* connecting two profunctors.

A pair of adjoint functors $F\dashv G$ determines *one single* profunctor (up to isomorphism), namely $F_*:=\hom(F-,-)$ which is the same as $G_*:=\hom(-,G-)$.

This is the case for a profunctor (as category) iff $\Bbb A$ is coreflective and $\Bbb B$ is reflective subcategory therein.

The two profunctors corresponding to the two directions in your example arise from the forget forgetful functor $\Bbb{TopGr}\to\Bbb{Top}$.

Comment: Gotta get this assignment in first.... by the way, are you a research mathematician?

Comment: Well.. Almost.. Unfortunately I haven't written enough papers, so currently I work as a programmer. What a waste of the world! :)

Comment: Yes, clearly a mis-allocation of scarce mathematical talent. Keep it up. Personally, I need to work hard and get my marks up so I can make a career out of this, otherwise, I might end up working as programmer, too...

Comment: I could be wrong, but the ideas described [here](http://www.ellerman.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/BrainFunctors.pdf) seem reminiscent of the the ideas in your paper.

Comment: On second thoughts, [here](http://www.ellerman.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Het-Theory.pdf) is a more mathematical (i.e. better) article by the same author.

Comment: Wow, thanks! $\,$

Comment: Berci, since you seem to be a bit of an expert on profunctors, any idea what [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143574/the-functor-mathbfd-rightarrow-mathbfprof-obtained-by-splitting-f) is called?

Answer (score 7):

What you've described is not a category, since it is not closed under composition of morphisms (since if you consider group $\to$ space $\to$ group, you allow the two arrows to be any continuous maps, and then there is little chance that there composite will be a group homomorphism).

Comment: Ah excellent point. Should have thought of that.