# The functor $\mathbf{D} \rightarrow \mathbf{Prof}$ obtained by "splitting" $F : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$ at each object of $\mathbf{D}.$

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology

(Write $\mathbf{Prof}$ for the category whose objects are categories and whose arrows are [profunctors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor).)

I'm pretty sure that every functor $F : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}$ yields a corresponding functor $F^\# : \mathbf{D} \rightarrow \mathbf{Prof}$ obtained by "splitting" $F$ at each object of $\mathbf{D}$ and using $\mathbf{D}$ to index the pieces.

**Question.** What is this construction called? **Is it discussed anywhere?**

Explicitly:

1. (Given $Y$ in $\mathbf{D}$). $F^\#(Y)$ is the category whose objects are those object $X \in \mathbf{C}$ satisfying $Y=F(X)$, and whose arrows are all arrows $f:X' \rightarrow X$ in $\mathbf{C}$ such that $F(X')=F(X)=Y.$
2. (Given $g : Y' \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathbf{D}$). $F^\#(g)$ is the profunctor of type $F^\#(Y') \nrightarrow F^\#(Y)$ such that if $X'$ and $X$ are objects of $F^\#(Y')$ and $F^\#(Y)$ respectively, then $F^\#(g)(X',X)$ is just $\mathbf{C}(X',X).$ The left and right actions are defined in the obvious ways.

Comment: It is a version (or generalization) of the *Grothendieck construction*: if we want to represent all functors, not only Grothendieck fibrations, we need ${\bf Prof}$ instead of ${\bf Cat}$. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction

Comment: @Berci, thanks for the comment. Have you seen this discussed anywhere? I mean the case with $\mathbf{Prof}$ instead of $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: I don't really remember having seen it written.. But, should be well known.

Comment: @Berci, I've been thinking about some foundational things of late, but lack anyone to bounce my ideas off (and I'm now in undergraduate computer science, not mathematics unfortunately, so finding collaborators is getting harder). Would you be interested in hearing my thoughts, and if they interest you, possibly collaborating in an informal way?

Comment: Well, ok. Why not.. Would you post it somewhere or send me on email, or how?

Comment: @Berci, email would be good. It's very 'diagrammatic' so it will take me awhile to get my thoughts down onto paper to send them, and I'm very busy right now. But in a couple of weeks I'm going to have a lot more time, and I'll write something. What's your email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make some adjustment to your definition, namely you require that

> $F^\#(Y)$ is the category whose objects are those $X \in \mathbf C$ such that  $F(X)=Y$ and whose morphisms are those morphisms $f \in \mathbf C[X,X']$ such that $F(f)=1_Y$

and that

> for every $g \colon Y \to Y'$ in $\mathbf C$ we have that $F^\#$ is the distributor defined on objects as
>   $F^\#(g)(X,X') = \{ f \in \mathbf C[X,X'] \mid F(f)=g \}$ and on morphism as 
>   $F^\#(g)(f,h)(\alpha) = h\circ\alpha\circ f$, when ever $f \colon X \to X'$, $h \colon Y \to Y'$, $\alpha \colon X' \to Y$ is in $F\#(g)(X',Y)$

what you get is the definition of generalized fibration as introduced in Streicher's notes (from a Benabou's seminar) [*Distributors at work*](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/FIBR/DiWo.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the link; that is actually a very well-written introduction to "distributors."

Comment: @goblin it is indeed, the part I'm referring to is the last section *Distributors and generalized fibrations*.